# Noninverting Amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier, non-inverting

I don't understand why \$ v_i = v_{in} - v_1 \$. Is \$v_{i}\$ supposed to be the inverting input or the noninverting input voltage?

[image]

Comment: For my opinion a rather confusing description: "...vi becomes smaller as vo" which means: Input smaller as outpout - not a real novel recognition. And "..v1 become larger" - larger than what?

Answer (score 1):

\$ v_{in} \$ is the non-inverting input.  \$ v_1 \$ is the inverting input.  \$ v_{i}\$ is the *voltage difference* between the inverting and non-inverting input.  It's drawn between the inputs of the OpAmp.  That's how the book have defined it for the purposes of discussion.  Thus \$ v_i = v_{in} - v_1 \$.

*p.s.* Naming the three variables \$ v_i \$, \$ v_{in} \$, \$ v_1 \$ is just begging for dyslexic errors.